# use of std::ends() and freeze(false)

Tags: c++, stream, std

I am looking over some legacy code and there is a fair amount of `stringstream` usage. The code is generating messages generally from various types ok so far. Apart from the fact that it is in some cases doing the following:

```
   std::ostringstream f1;
   f1 << sDirectory << mFileName << sFileExtension << '\0';
```

and in others doing (Just illustration)

```
   std::ostringstream f1;
   f1 << sDirectory << mFileName << sFileExtension << std::ends;
```

I believe These calls are because further on it accesses `f1.str().c_str()` and needs to null terminate it.

Is there any difference in these calls ? I see from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ends that std::ends doesn't flush, is std::ends different across different platforms (Linux/Windows/Mac)? Should I prefer one over the other?

Further to that I read that there should be a call to `freeze(false)` on the stringstream later in the scope (after `str()` use) to allow the buffer to be deallocated (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ostrstream/freeze). Again (possibly I misread or misunderstood) but there is no call to `freeze(false)` so does that indicate that every stream above is leaking?

N.B. FYI This is Visual Studio 2005/Windows 7 but I don't know if that has any baring.

Apologies if I'm being dense...

Comment: for clarity, I would stick with the std::ends vs. '\0'. You can do some profiling on the app to determine if the code is leaking

Comment: I'm just doubting my own experience now - I don't think I've ever seen the freeze command TBH

Comment: `ostringstream` in your example has nothing to do with `ostrstream`, which is where `freeze(false)` is required.

Comment: @Cubbi I think I was having a bad day when I posted this - thanks for looking and spotting that though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::ends` is defined as having the following effect:

> Inserts a null character into the output sequence: calls `os.put(charT())`.

When `charT` is `char`, it is value initialized to have the value 0, which is equivalent to the character literal `\0`. So when `charT` is `char`, which it usually is, the two lines of code are exactly the same.

However, using `std::ends` will work well even when the character type of your stream is not `char`.

Comment: Thanks - yes it's obvious now you said it. If we are dealing with wide characters it may be different. Thanks